# Angular orderBy not re-running after ng-click changes order string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a a collection of panels each with a simple list of items that needs to either be sorted by 'computedLoad' or 'Name'. I have the following objects and methods to accomplish this generically over all of the panels (only showing one panel among many).

```
        scope.orderBy = {
            name: {
                displayName: "Name",
                sort: "Name",
                reverse: false
            },
            load: {
                displayName: "Load",
                sort: "-computedLoad",
                reverse:false
            }
        };
        scope.selectOrder = function (panel, order) {
            timeout(function () {
                panel.activeOrder = order;
            });
        };
        scope.panels = {
            methods: {
                activeOrder: scope.orderBy.name
            }
        };
```

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="list-label"><a>Order By:</a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="order in orderBy"><a href="#" ng-click="selectOrder(panels.methods, order)">{{order.displayName}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li ng-repeat="item in suite.Methods | orderBy:panel.methods.activeOrder.sort"><a href="#"><span class="text">{{item.Name}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

The `selectOrder` method doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/puxoxi/1/

Answer (score 0):

Setting panel.activeOrder happens asynchronously, so it is outside of angulars so called "digest cycle".
To make angular re-evaluate your scope, use the [$apply function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

It could look like this:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
  panel.activeOrder = order;
});
```

Comment: $timeout also runs the $digest. It still doesn't work for some reason. Seems strange. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't aware of that. I assume that just setting the activeOrder directly (without timeout) isn't an option..?